# Running only certain canopy tests as specified on command line

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

Let's say I have the following simple [Canopy](https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/) test program:

```ml
open System
open canopy.runner.classic
open canopy.configuration
open canopy.classic

canopy.configuration.chromeDir <- System.AppContext.BaseDirectory

start chrome

"test 1" &&& fun _ ->

    ...

"test 2" &&& fun _ ->

    ...

"test 3" &&& fun _ ->

    ...

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    
    run()

    quit()

    0
```

When I run this program:

```
dotnet run
```

All three tests are run.

Let's say that by default, I want to run `test 1` and `test 2`. But sometimes, I'd like to only run `test 3`.

What's the recommended way to set this up in Canopy?

Something like passing command line options would be fine:

```
dotnet run               # Run the default tests

dotnet run -- test-3     # Run test 3
```

Alternatively, I guess I could have `test 3` be in a whole separate project. But that seems like alot of overhead just to have a separate test.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do this, but it seems pretty easy to manage manually:

```
let defaultTests () =
    "test 1" &&& fun _ -> ()
    "test 2" &&& fun _ -> ()

let test3 () =
    "test 3" &&& fun _ -> ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args : _[]) =
    let arg =
        if args.Length = 0 then "default"
        else args.[0]
    match arg with
        | "default" -> defaultTests ()
        | "test-3" -> test3 ()
        | _ -> failwith $"Unknown arg: {arg}"
    run()
    quit()
    0
```

The trick is to make sure that only the tests you want to run actually get defined at run-time.

Comment: Great answer, Brian! Thank you!